# Add styles to a custom sidebar region in Zen

Tags: 7, theming

I am using [Zen](https://drupal.org/project/zen) as a theme.

I want to know how I can create a third sidebar and apply the styles in `responsive.css` to it.

I already know how to create a custom region and render it.

Answer (score 0):

You create a sidebar region as same like other regions. And just edit the css and add the new region class there in existing sidebar css.

```
.sidebar1{
  background-color:yellow;
}
.sidebar1,
.sidebar_new{
  background-color:yellow;
}
```